# Prove that $|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_{k}| \ge |a_{1}| - \sum\limits_{k=2}^{n} |a_{k}|$.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, summation, proof-writing, absolute-value

I am abjectly disappointed that I could not prove this statement on my own.  I have tried it directly and by contradiction but hit a wall.  Here is the statement (again) and my proof (thus far):

Prove that $|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_{k}| \ge |a_{1}| - \sum\limits_{k=2}^{n} |a_{k}|$.

Proof:
Let $a_{1}, ..., a_{n}$ be real numbers. Consider $|a_{1}| - \sum\limits_{k=2}^{n} |a_{k}|$. Then $|a_{1}| - \sum\limits_{k=2}^{n} |a_{k}| \leq ||a_{1}| - \sum\limits_{k=2}^{n} |a_{k}||$ holds by a property of the Absolute Value function $\forall a_{1},...,a_{n} \in \mathbb{R}$. Now, by the Reverse Triangle Inequality, we have $||a_{1}| - \sum\limits_{k=2}^{n} |a_{k}|| \leq |a_{1} - \sum\limits_{k=2}^{n} a_{k}|$.

I then proceeded to show that $|a_{1} - \sum\limits_{k=2}^{n} a_{k}| \leq \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_{k} \leq |\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_{k}|$ by considering different cases for $a_{1}$ and $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_{k}$ (e.g. $a_{1}, \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_{k} > 0$ as one case out of four), and was able to show one case to hold but am struggling with the others.  Is there a more simplified way to write this proof?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! This has hurt my brain for weeks now :(

Comment: **Hint:** try starting by using the fact that $\color{blue}{|x+y|\ge |x| - |y|}$ (i.e. the reverse triangle inequality works with a plus sign in the left-hand side too).

Comment: I am assuming this is all I would need to complete my proof? I would not even have to show the cases for my real numbers, no?
But how is this fact true for all x,y in R? Is there a proof behind this?

Comment: My approach I had in mind was the one posted in Falcon's answer. And to prove that $|x+y|\ge |x|-|y|$ for all $x,y\in \Bbb{R}$, note that it just follows from the usual triangle inequality. That is, use $|u+v|\le |u|+|v|$, with $u = x+y$ and $v=-y$.

Comment: I will try out your and Falcon's method.  Thank you!
Do you consider my original thought process to go nowhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have
$$\left|\sum_{k = 1}^n a_k\right| = \left|a_1 + \sum_{k = 2}^n a_k\right| \ge |a_1| - \left|\sum_{k = 2}^n a_k\right|  \ge |a_1| - \sum_{k= 2}^n|a_k|,$$
where the first inequality comes from $|a+b| \ge |a| - |b|$ and the second one comes from $|a + b| \le |a| + |b|$.

**EDIT:** To prove that $|a+b| \ge |a| - |b|$ just remark that
$$|a| = |a + b - b| \le |a+b| + |b|$$
by triangular inequality.

Comment: My textbook never showed how $|a + b| \geq |a| - |b|$. Is there a proof behind this?
Thank you for responding.

Comment: Ok, I wrote an argument to prove the statement.

Comment: I followed Minus One-Twelfth and your comments and succeeded.  I appreciate your feedback!  :)
I hope I can help you one day, but I assure that you are way more skilled in Mathematics than I am.  Best wishes and cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much, you too! :) If you agree with the answer you can click on the "V" to show that this answer has been solved.

Comment: Done! I will check out more of your content on any other questions you seem to solve (if it is relevant to my project).

Comment: Actually, I have posted another Real Analysis question on a theorem I am reading and am comprehending. There is one part I cannot understand when writing the proof. Would you be able to help? A link is provided here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3969777/real-analysis-theorem-question

Answer (score 2):

First observe $$\begin{align} -\left|\sum_{k = 2}^{n}a_k \right| &\le 0\\
\left|\sum_{k = 1}^{n}a_k\right| - |a_1| &\ge0 \end{align}$$
And the second inequality follows from triangle inequality

Comment: I see. Then this implies that I would add $|a_{1}|$ to both sides of the inequality, take the difference of the sum of $|a_{k}|$ (where $k \geq 2$) on both sides of the inequality, and then show that $|a_{1} + ... + a_{n}| \geq |a_{1} + ... + a_{n}| - (|a_{2}| + ... + |a_{n}|).$

Comment: i think you have to just then do the second expression is greater than the first as one is positive and other is negative