# Real Analysis Theorem Question

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, induction

This is a Theorem covered in my textbook:

Let $n \geq 2$ be an integer. Suppose that $b_{1}, b_{2}, \ldots , b_{n}$ are positive real numbers that are not all equal. If $b_{1}b_{2}\cdots b_{n} = 1$, then prove that $b_{1} + b_{2} + \ldots + b_{n} > n.$

I know that mathematical induction will be used and why it was used. I also fully comprehend the base case and will just include the ind. hypothesis/step.

Suppose the result is valid for some positive integer $p \geq 2$. Let $b_{1}, b_{2}, \ldots ,b_{p}, b_{p+1}$ be positive real numbers that are not all equal and satisfy $b_{1}b_{2}\cdots b_{p}b_{p+1} = 1$. Without loss of generality, we may assume that the numbers are in increasing order: $b_{1} \leq b_{2} \leq \ldots \leq b_{p} \leq b_{p+1}$.

This is where I am stuck:

By the assumptions on these numbers, we must have $b_{1} < 1 < b_{p+1}$.

My question is: why? I tried proving this with the given information (from above) but had little to no success. I can intuitively see why this makes sense, but cannot show this step.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "then prove that b1+b2+...+bn" .... Then prove *WHAT* about $b_1 + b_2 + .... + b_n$?

Comment: Corrected!  I forgot to include 
$b_{1} + . . . + b_{n} > n$. My apologies!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means

Comment: "By the assumptions on these numbers, we must have b1<1<bp+1".  If any were less than $1$ and none were more than $1$ the product will be less than $1$.  If any were more than $1$ and none were less than $1$ the product would be more than $1$.  So as the product is one, they must either all be $1$ or at least one will be less than and at least one will be more than $1$.  You are told they aren't equal, so the smallest one, $b_1$ must be less than $1$ and the largest one $b_p$ must be more than $1$.

Comment: No formal proof is needed to justify what you said @fleablood?
I completely agree with you and it makes sense, but I just did not know if the author skipped a step in the theorem and did not prove this or if it need not to be proved.

Comment: My argument  *was* a formal proof.

Comment: Yes, my mistake.
I meant formally prove that part, but you showed it informally. I appreciate that too and for you to take the time to help me out! :)

Comment: You're going to have trouble with your induction.  If $b_1....b_pb_{p+1} = 1$ then $b_1.......b_p< 1$ and your induction hypthesis might not hold.

Comment: There's nothing informal about my argument.  it is as rigorous and as thorough as was needed or was to be expected.  Again, it *was* a formal proof.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. 
The theorem used induction, so I will be attempting it again.

Answer (score 2):

Since they are not all equal, there is $i,j \in \{1, \ldots, p+1\}$ with $i< j$, such that $b_i \neq b_j$ and as your sequence $\{b_1, \ldots, b_{p+1}\}$ is ordered you must have $b_1 \le b_i < b_j \le b_{p+1}$. Moreover, if $b_1 \ge 1$, then $b_{p+1} b_1 > 1$ which contradicts your induction hypothesis. The same argument holds for $b_{p+1} \le 1$.

Comment: long time no see! Thank you again for formally explaining this! Your argument makes valid sense.
To reiterate your logic for showing $b_{p+1} < 1$: if $b_{p+1} < 1$, then $b_{1}b_{p+1} < 1$ which would also contradict the induction hypothesis.

Comment: Yes you've understood!

Answer (score 1):

Indirectly if we assume that $b_1 < 1 < b_{p+1}$ is NOT true, there are two cases:

- $b_{p+1} \le 1$, which implies that $0 < b_1 \le \ldots \le b_{p+1} < 1$ (one of the inequalities being strict), implying $\prod b_i < 1$, or
- $1 \le b_1$ which similarly would imply $\prod b_i > 1$.

And both cases lead to a contradiction with $\prod b_i = 1$.