# How to prove $|x+x_1+...+x_n| \ge |x|-(|x_1|+...+|x_n|)$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, real-numbers, absolute-value

I'd like to return to college, which I had to leave due to money constraints, but now I'm preparing myself for real analysis. In my exercise book, there is a problem for showing an inequality:

$\forall x,x_1,...,x_n \in \mathbb{R}; n \in \mathbb{N}: |x+x_1+...+x_n| \geq |x|-(|x_1|+...+|x_n|)$

I have spent yesterday's evening, trying to somehow come up with an elegant solution, using the following inequalities I know to be true:
$-|x|\leq x \leq |x|$;
$|x+y| \leq |x| + |y|$;
$|x-y| \geq ||x|-|y||$.

My latest strategy has been to show that $|x|-|x_1|\leq |x-x_1|$ and subsequently $|x-x_1| \leq |x+x_1|$, the following $x_2, ..., x_n$ would then be easy to prove. However, the second inequality doesn't even hold and I'm stuck.

Comment: Use `\Bbb R` to get $\Bbb R$

Comment: You can use MathJax in the title.

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3969728/42969 – both found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%7Cx%2Bx_1%2B...%2Bx_n%7C%20%5Cge%20%7Cx%7C-(%7Cx_1%7C%2B...%2B%7Cx_n%7C)%24)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. If $y = x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n$, we have
$$|x+y| \geqslant |x| - |y|$$
$$|x_1|+|x_2|+\dots+|x_n| \geqslant |y|$$
both by triangle inequality.

Answer (score 0):

You go by induction. First prove that for $x,x_1$ it holds $|x+x_1| \geq |x|- |x_1|$, and this is simply the triangle inequality (or reversed triangle inequality if you like). Then consider $x, x_1, \dots,x_n,  x_{n+1}$ assuming you have the thesis for $n$ numbers instead of $n+1$.

Consider $x, x_1, \dots, x_{n}+x_{n+1}$. Now apply the inductive hypothesis to get

$$ |x+x_1 + x_2 + \dots x_{n+1}| \geq |x|- (|x_1| + \dots + |x_n + x_{n+1}|) \geq\\ \geq |x|- (|x_1| + \dots + |x_n| + |x_{n+1}|)$$

by the triangle inequality applied to $|x_n + x_{n+1}|$.

Good luck with your comeback!

Comment: Oh my God, I am so disappointed in myself! Thank you so much. :)

Comment: Oh don't worry, these kind of proofs will come naturally with experience. Keep on doing exercises!